# Why isn't my Arduino code printing latitude and longitude to the serial monitor?

Tags: arduino, gps

I'm using  a NodeMCU with a NEO6MV2 GPS module.

Code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

long lati,lon; // create variable for latitude and longitude object
static const int RXPin = 5;  // (RX GPS -> D1 MCU)
static const int TXPin = 4;  // (TX GPS -> D2 MCU)
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial (RXPin, TXPin);

TinyGPS gps; // create gps object

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // connect serial
  gpsSerial.begin(4800); // connect gps sensor
}

int i=0;

void loop() {
  Serial.println("\nTest");
  Serial.println(i);
  delay(500);
  while(gpsSerial.available()) {
    // check for gps data
    if(gps.encode(gpsSerial.read())) {
      // encode gps data
      gps.get_position(&lati, &lon); // get latitude and longitude
      // display position
      Serial.print("Position: ");
      Serial.print("lat: ");Serial.print(lati);Serial.print(" "); // print latitude
      Serial.print("lon: ");Serial.println(lon); // print longitude
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

For those who know about this, is my GPS module connected to my NodeMCU correctly (TX, RX pins) i.e. TX(GPS) -> D2(MCU) and RX(GPS) -> D1(MCU)? Are other pins advised?

Assuming my pins are connected correctly - and I know the GPS module itself works correctly - why is my serial monitor not printing the latitude and longitude?

I have been through so many tutorials, variations of libraries, YouTube videos etc. but there doesn't seem to be anything for connecting directly a NodeMCU to a GPS module and printing on the serial monitor and readable code anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- Don't use delay.  During that 500ms, the GPS device can send 500 characters.  But the input buffer only has room for 64, so most of the characters will be lost.
- Most GPS devices run at 9600.
- You are printing too much.  This also causes GPS characters to be lost, because the sketch must wait for the prints to complete.  This, and several other problems, are described on the NeoGPS [Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Troubleshooting.md).

Here is a [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) version of your sketch.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>

static const int RXPin = 5;  // (RX GPS -> D1 MCU)
static const int TXPin = 4;  // (TX GPS -> D2 MCU)
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial (RXPin, TXPin);

NMEAGPS gps; // create gps object

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // connect serial
  gpsSerial.begin(9600); // default for most is 9600
  Serial.println("\nTest");
}

uint32_t loopCount = 0;

void loop() {

  if (gps.available( gpsSerial )) {
    // get the structure that contains all the parsed values
    gps_fix fix = gps.read();

    Serial.println( loopCount );

    // display position
    Serial.print("Position: ");
    if (fix.valid.location) {
      Serial.print("lat: "); Serial.print( fix.latitude(), 6 ); Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print("lon: "); Serial.println( fix.longitude(), 6 );
    } else {
      Serial.println( '?' );
    }
  }

  loopCount++;
}
```

It only prints the `loopCount` when a new GPS fix is complete (once per second).  This shows you how *fast* the processor is when compared to the character rate.

If you want to try it, NeoGPS is available from the Arduino Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch-> Include Library-> Manage Libraries**, or from the link above.  Also, NeoGPS is smaller, faster, more reliable and more accurate than all other libraries.